# Ubuntu 13.10 - Sound stopped working

Tags: 13.10, sound, configuration, pulseaudio, alsa

I've been running Ubuntu 13.10 since it's release and haven't had any issues with the sound up until this morning.  When I logged in I found that it was no longer working.  Below is a screen shot of my sound settings as well as the properties of the card I had been using.  As you can see, my devices are being detected and set to play.  When I run alsamixer everything appears normal but the auto-mute feature is missing.  I've tried `alsa force-reload` as well as uninstalling and re-installing alsa.  I've also tried the suggestions listed in the comments section here:

http://itsfoss.com/fix-sound-ubuntu-1304-quick-tip/

I'm not sure what the problem is or what else to try.  Could it be an obscure configuration issue?  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image: Sound Display]

```
properties:
        alsa.card = "0"
        alsa.card_name = "HDA Intel PCH"
        alsa.long_card_name = "HDA Intel PCH at 0xd2710000 irq 46"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
        device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:1b.0"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0"
        device.bus = "pci"
        device.vendor.id = "8086"
        device.vendor.name = "Intel Corporation"
        device.product.id = "1e20"
        device.product.name = "7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller"
        device.form_factor = "internal"
        device.string = "0"
        device.description = "Built-in Audio"
        module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My sound working again.  I do not know how or why though.  I woke it up from sleep to find everything working as before.  Maybe it was an errant configuration issue.  Still, I hope this link helps people in the future:

http://itsfoss.com/fix-sound-ubuntu-1304-quick-tip/